# Add to a static list in a constructor

Tags: c++

I don't know how to grab the object itself I am creating and add it to the static list.

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Random {
  public:
  Random() {
    array.push_back(ITSELF or this or something...);
  }
  private:
  static std::vector<Random> array;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use ```this```, though ```this``` is a pointer to it's invoker (so, ```Random*```). If you defined ```array``` as ```std::vector<Random*> array;``` (or using smart pointers), it should work.

Comment: Oh, of course, thanks

Comment: With the definition of `std::vector<Random> array` It will never be the object itself. At very best - it might be a **copy** of the object. To reference already existing object, you may use pointers, as already suggested, but then, you would need to take care not to dereference the invalid pointers (if you aren't removing the objects from the list, on destruction).